# django social auth not returning first_name and last_name when creating a profile - django 1.5

Tags: django, django-socialauth, django-1.5

Am using a custom user model to maintain user details with django 1.5, below is my code. When using social auth, everything seems to be working fine accept first_name and last_name.

In my table table structure, I do not have first_name and last_name, instead, I have one field  full name.

but, i did create a method in the manager to accept first and last names and combine them. but, still am receiving empty values, any advise on why this is happening?

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    UserManager()
    """
    def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, first_name='', last_name='', **extra_fields):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a username')

        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=UserManager.normalize_email(email),
            full_name='%s %s' % (first_name, last_name),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    Accounts/User
    """

    GENDERS = (
        (u'M', _('Male')),
        (u'F', _('Female')),
    )


    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, numbers and '
                    '@/./+/-/_ characters'),
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[\w.@+-]+$'), _('Enter a valid username.'), 'invalid')
        ])


    email           = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)


    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                    'site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    # user details and information
    full_name           = models.CharField(_('full name'), max_length=30, )
    date_of_birth       = models.DateField(_('birthday'), null=True, blank=True)
    bio                 = models.TextField(_('biography / about you'), null=True, blank=True, help_text=_('Biography / About you'))
    gender              = models.CharField(_('gender'), max_length=1, blank=True, null=True, choices=GENDERS)

    # follows / followers
    followings           = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Relationship', symmetrical=False, related_name='followers')

    objects             = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'date_of_birth', 'full_name',]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django-social-auth doesn't work like that when creating user, instead when calling `create_user` in your manager, it just passes the username and the email as you can see [here](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/social_auth/backends/pipeline/user.py#L63). Later in the pipeline more fields in your user model are update when this is [called](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/social_auth/backends/pipeline/user.py#L109), but as the code says, it does a `getattr(user, name, None)` which in you case for `first_name` and `last_name`, returns `None` since those fields aren't defined in your model.

You can trick the system by defining some properties in your model, something like this:

```
class User(...):
    @property
    def first_name(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_first_name'):
            self._first_name = self.full_name.split(' ', 1)[0]
        return self._first_name

    @first_name.setter
    def first_name(self, value):
        self._first_name = value
        self.build_full_name()

    @property
    def last_name(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_last_name'):
            self._last_name = self.full_name.split(' ', 1)[-1]
        return self._last_name

    @first_name.setter
    def last_name(self, value):
        self._last_name = value
        self.build_full_name()

    def build_full_name(self):
        self.full_name = ' '.join([self._first_name, self._last_name])
```